# TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ Ignores Timezone

Tags: oracle, plsql, timestamp-with-timezone

Running Oracle PL/SQL version 12.1 on Linux Red Hat 7.7

I'm trying to convert the following varchar fields to timestamp with timezone. The timestamp is formatted like MMDDYYHH24MMSS. The timezone seems to be formatted with +/- then 3-4 digits, maybe ranging from -1200 to +1200, with no zero-padding. Example:

ts | tz

041320174533 | -700

I want the following timestamp with timezone:

ts_tz

2020-04-13 17:45:33 -07:00

My attempt (imagine the hard-coded '041320174533' and '-700' values were replaced with `ts` and `tz` respectively):

```
-- Input to to_timestamp_tz '041320174533 -700'
select
     to_timestamp('041320174533', 'MMDDYYHH24MISS') as dt
    ,to_timestamp_tz('041320174533' || ' ' || substr('-700', 1, 1) || '0' || substr('-700', 2, 3), 
        'MMDDYYHH24MISS TZHTZM') as dt_tz
from dual;
```

But the result lacks timezone and no update to timestamp. to_timestamp and to_timestamp_tz have the same result:

dt | dt_tz

2020-04-13 17:45:33 | 2020-04-13 17:45:33

How can I concatenate these and get the expected result with timestamp attached?

Comment: Explanation of datetime formats [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

Comment: I just ran your code and it gives me the correct result both for the timestamp and the timestamp with time zone. Are you sure that you are **displaying** the data as it should be? What is your session's `nls_timestamp_tz_format`?

Comment: As for the time zone being given in the format -700 instead of -0700, your solution will work, but it will NOT work if the TZH is already two digits. Instead of `'0' || substr...` you should have `lpad(substr..., 4, '0')` - that will left-pad the string '700' with zeros to the left, up to a length of 4 characters.

Comment: Thanks. I see in `V$NLS_PARAMETERS` my session format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`. So I'll try `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'` before each application query.

Comment: You should try to find out why `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` is set to that value, as it doesn't seem reasonable. If you are using SQL Developer, you can change that in Preferences. As an individual user, if you use SQL\*Plus, you can put a command in your `login.sql`, but the DBA should do that for all users, in `glogin.sql`.

Comment: I tried setting this in `login.sql`: `SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'`, but I got: `unknown SET option beginning "NLS_TIMEST..."`

Comment: `SET` is not a valid stand-alone SQL statement - it is a clause in an `ALTER SESSION` statement. You are missing `ALTER SESSION` before the keyword `SET`.

Comment: I use `SET` for other statements in my `login.sql`, and they work fine. But didn't know `ALTER SESSION` worked here too. That did the trick +1 Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: SET is a SQL\*Plus command. ALTER SESSION is a SQL statement. Different things!